# Add a filter on a DbSet that is included on a related DbSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

The following are some stuffs behind the scene.

```
public class User : BaseTransactionModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
    public int TransactionHistoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual TransactionHistory TransactionHistory { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionHistory
{
    public int TransactionHistoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class BaseTransactionModel
{

    public int TransactionHistoryId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public virtual TransactionHistory TransactionHistory { get; set; }
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

With the above entities, I am trying to get all the **Transactions** from a **User** on a specified Date.

So I tried including both **User** and **TransactionHistory** on the Transaction DbSet:

```
Context.Transaction
    .Include(t => t.User)
    .Include(t => t.TransactionHistory)
    ...
```

I wanted to add a where clause that filter the transaction from the date in transaction history entities:

```
Context.Transaction
    .Include(t => t.User)
    .Include(t => t.TransactionHistory)
    .Where(t => t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime <= StartDateFilter && t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime >= EndDateFilter)
```

but could not able to do so. Since TransactionHistory is also a list of entity (or whatever it is called).

What could be the possible solution to get what I am trying to achieve ?

*PS: I am new to EF and the title could be misleading. If so, feel free to update it.*

Comment: Your model-classes don't look like they're supposed to. Try to research, how relationships should be defined in classes (with navigation-properties).

Comment: @Nikolaus I fix my grievance on the sample classes above. Thanks for the suggestion I'll make sure to take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to rethink your class design e.g.

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Transaction> TransactionHistory { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {    
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Then to get the transactions like you require your query could be something like this:

```
 var result = Context.User
                .Where(u => u.UserId == myguid)
                .Select(t => new
                {
                    UserId = t.UserId,
                    Transactions = t.TransactionHistory.Where(x => x.CreatedDateTime >= StartDateFilter && x.CreatedDateTime <= EndDateFilter)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: "You might need to rethink your class design"... I know that this could be one of the solutions but I don't want to do it because this is someone else's project that I am trying to explore and I'm avoiding on modifying any of its class models. If there is no possible solution other than this, then it could be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is to be able to filter included entities.

There is two way to filter include Entity:

- Using a projection (See @majita answer)
- Using a third party library

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ Query IncludeFilter allow easily filter included entities.

```
Context.Transaction
    .IncludeFilter(t => t.User)
    .IncludeFilter(t => t.TransactionHistory
        .Where(x => x.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime <= StartDateFilter && x.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime >= EndDateFilter))
```

Under the hood, the library does exactly a projection.

One limitation is all `Include` but now be called with `IncludeFilter` even if no filter is specified such as the `User`.

Wiki: [EF+ Query Include Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
Context.Transaction
    .Where(t => t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime <= StartDateFilter && t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime >= EndDateFilter)
.Select(x=> new {x.User,x.TransactionHistory});
```

OR This

```
Context.Transaction
.Where(t => t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime <= StartDateFilter && t.TransactionHistory.CreatedDateTime >= EndDateFilter)
.Include(t => t.User)
.Include(t => t.TransactionHistory)
```

Comment: In cause of the wrong NavigationProperties, this can't work